# CakePHP validation not detecting form field

Tags: php, forms, validation, cakephp

I have a form where users can upload images, and I'm printing it to the page like so:

```
<?php echo $this->Form->label('file', 'Image file', array('class' => 'col-lg-1 control-label')); ?>
```

Then, in the model I'm setting up validation like so:

```
public $validate = array(
    'file' => array(
        'required' => array(
            'rule' => array('notEmpty'),
            'message' => 'You must select an image to upload'
        ),
        'extension' => array(
            'rule' => array('extension', array('png')),
            'message' => 'Images must be in PNG format'
        ),
        'size' => array(
            'rule' => array('fileSize', '<', '1MB'),
            'message' => 'Images must be no larger than 1MB'
        ),
        'goodUpload' => array(
            'rule' => 'uploadError',
            'message' => 'Something went wrong with the upload, please try again'
        )
    )
);
```

However, Cake doesn't seem to be associating the form field with the validation rule, as if I select an image to upload I always get "You must select an image to upload" as a form error. I've made sure the form has `enctype="multipart/form-data"`.

Is this happening because `file` isn't a database field? How can I make cake run some validation on `file`?

Edit: Here's my entire form, as requested: http://pastebin.com/SbSbtDP9

Comment: Can you post code for your entire form?

Comment: Sure, had to upload it to Pastebin though as it's pretty lengthy.

Comment: Have you looked at the validating uploads section on this page: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html

Comment: can you put your controller code also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can validate fields that are not in the database, long as you have the correct field name in the correct model.

From what I can see in your code it seems your outputting a label instead of an actual input, for the image upload I would try

```
echo $this->Form->create('Model', array('type'=>'file'));
echo $this->Form->input('file', array('type'=>'file'));
echo $this->Form->submit('Upload Image'):
echo $this->Form->end();
```

For the validation I would try something like with the rest of your validate options (size, etc...) CakePHP usually throws an error on notEmpty on File Uploads. So just checking for the extension type is usually good enough.

```
public $validate = array(
   'file' => array(
     'rule' => array(
     'extension', array('jpeg', 'jpg')
     'message' => 'You must supply a file.'
     )
   )
);
```

Majority of time in CakePHP for Image Uploading I resort to a plugin such as https://github.com/josegonzalez/cakephp-upload it does validation and upload handling all in one.

Comment: He has `$this->Form->form(...)` in his code.  Don't have you have to do something special for fields that aren't in the database?

Comment: No, but his Form->create needs a 'type'=>'file' in the options array.

Comment: Ok, just looked at the pastebin, since I can't add a comment on the original question, I'll comment here! Darn low rep :(

What if you change $this->Form->file(); to $this->Form->input('file', array('type'=>'file')); ? Does it validate?

Answer (score 0):

Managed to figure it out. Turns out having the `notEmpty` validation on a file fieldnever works, it always thinks there's nothing there and so always throws that validation message.

Worked around it by writing my own validation method.